# Need easy formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

In image I have wrote down an example. I need easy formula where I can get result for below criteria.

```
A1>150000000,
A1<-150000000,
B1>3%,
B1<-3%
```

Right now i am using this formula.

```
=MID(IF((OR(H50>150000000,H50<-150000000)),", variance greater than threshold","") &  (IF(ABS(I50)>3,", % Greater than threshold","")),3,999)
```

But, it gives me result even if 1 criteria met. I want result if all criterias met. Something like " Variance and % is greater than threshold".

Thank You.

Comment: I tested your formula and it seems OK to me. Can you provide actual vs. expected outcomes for your sample table?

Comment: you're missing the % in `(ABS(I50)>3`

Comment: The  sample data & the screen shot are different your criterion are in `A1& B1`  but in formula you are testing `H50 & I50` !!

Comment: I'm getting `Variance greater than threshold, % Greater than threshold`,,  now what else you need?

Comment: If I take this literally, you want to compare texts "Variance" and "%" with numbers.  Then your formula references H50 and I50.

Answer (score 1):

There is a contradiction in your request, so first we need to  clarify your intentions.

You say: *But, it gives me result even if 1 criteria met. I want result if all criterias met.* You also wrote 4 criterias, two for A1 and two for B1. However, since the two criterias for A1 are mutually exclusive as well as the two criterias for B1, all four criteria can not be met!

I understand that you actually want (expressed as a logical sentence):

*if ((A1 > 150000000) or (A1 < -150000000)) and ((B1 > 3%) or (B1 < -3%)) then return "Variance and percentage are greater than thresholds"*.

This can be written as a formula:

```
=IF(AND(ABS(A1)>150000000,ABS(B1)>3),"Variance and percentage are greater than thresholds","")
```

Note! It is not clear if your percentage values are actual percentages or scaled (3% => 3). You might need to adjust the formula accordingly.